# Mongoose: sort date doesn't work as date but text on my mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My sort on date doesn't work as date type but text type on my mongodb query.

I have a document "affaire" looking like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e32b42467e488e064972adf"
    },
    "Adresse": "22 rue des rosiers 75005 PARIS",
    "Date_de_prochaine_echeance": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1461715200000"
        }
    },
...
}
```

the mongoose declaration :

```
{
...
"Date_de_prochaine_echeance": { "type": "Date" },
...
}
```

My query looks like this

```
    affaire.find().sort([['Date_de_prochaine_echeance', -1]]).
      select("Adresse ").
      exec(function (err, affaire) { ...});
```

My insert looks like this (I notice that not all my dates are insert the same way, I'm full of shame) :

```
 new affaire({ ...
    "Date_acceptation": req.body.Date_acceptation||new Date(),
"Date_de_prochaine_echeance": new moment(req.body.Date_de_prochaine_echeance||"2099-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").toDate(),
    ...
});
```

nb : I've used the moment.js lib

The sort function doesn't work as it was a date field but text field. 
I see on some answer that the format of the date may not be good. But I don't get how to correct all my dates with ISODate("2018-03-16T06:30:00Z").

The date seems to be a proper date format since the Compass interface interprete correctly the date.

I'm working with mongoose, shouldn't it check for format?

Comment: The JSON file for your document looks really strange, as typically should look like this
`{"_id": ObjectId("5e32b42467e488e064972adf"),"Adresse": "22 rue des rosiers 75005 PARIS", "Date_de_prochaine_echeance": ISODate("2018-03-16T06:30:00Z")}`

Can you show us where and how you save the document on MongoDB?

Comment: Also, please don't use french or in general localized field names for your documents. That's because someone will probably mantain that at some point, and you can't be sure he/she knows the french :)

Comment: I'm doing some militantism to promote my native language :)
I will check to give you the info and edit my post.

Comment: Idk, I find more natural writing code in english, though I'm not english. Plus the reason I explained above

Comment: I also noticed this: if you try to create a Date object from that number you get an error
```var date = new Date('1461715200000')```
```Invalid Date```
So that could also be the reason your sort isn't working, simply because that is not considered a valid date by Javascript

Comment: when I use compass it translate properly the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it !

Everything was right but ... I had some null values in the sorted dates.

This is all the possible sort by date that my work or not (depending of your version of mongodb) :

```
Room.find({}).sort('-date').exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}).sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}).sort({date: 'desc'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}).sort({date: 'descending'}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}).sort([['date', -1]]).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}, null, {sort: '-date'}, function(err, docs) { ... });
Room.find({}, null, {sort: {date: -1}}, function(err, docs) { ... });
```